# Can you pass an environment variables into kubectl exec without bash -c?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a script in a pod called `script01` and it can take parameters.
I run the script through the following:

```
POD=<pod name>
runScript="kubectl -n nmspc exec $POD -- script01"
$runScript --command "do stuff"
```

The reason I run it this way is that I don't have access to create a script on the local machine but I do have access to the script on the pod.

The issue is I want to pass the IP of the host machine to the pod and wanted to do it using an environment variable. I've tried using bash -c to pass the parameters but when calling the script through the variable, it doesn't append the parameters.

```
runScript="kubectl -n nmspc exec $POD -- bash -c \"export curIP=123 && script01\""
```

but it does work if I run it with 
`$runScript --command "do stuff"`

How can I pass an environment variable to the pod but still be able to call the script through the variable?

Comment: To explain part of what's happening to your parameters -- `bash -c '...'` interprets `...` as the entirety of the script to run. Any parameters after that argument become `$0`, `$1`, etc in that context of that `...` script -- but if the script never reads those arguments, they simply get ignored.

Comment: You might consider a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) as a more robust way to get some command running in the cluster somewhere.  I'd try to reserve `kubectl exec` for debugging.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` exports values passed in `key=value` pairs into the environment of any program it's used to invoke.

```
kubectl -n nmspc exec "$POD" -- env curIP=123 script01
```

Note that you should **never** use `$runScript` or any other unquoted expansion to invoke a shell command. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*

---

As an example of how you *could* keep `bash -c` in place but have your command work, consider:

```
runScript() {
  kubectl -n nmspc exec "$POD" -- bash -c 'export curIP=123 && script01 "$@"' _ "$@"
}

runScript --command "do stuff"
```

Here, `runScript` is a *function*, not a string variable, and it explicitly passes its entire argument list through to `kubectl`. Similarly, the copy of `bash` started by `kubectl` explicitly passes *its* argument list (after the `$0` placeholder `_`) through to `script01`, so the end result is your arguments making it through to your final program.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I've read the link you posted but given my circumstances, I had to go through with it. The solution you provided works perfectly given my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Just use sh:

```sh
kubectl -n nmspc exec "$POD" -- /bin/sh -c 'curIP=123 script01'
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy exact I forgot the quotes around arguments, fixed it

Comment: Much better -- this should indeed work now. That said, the way you're using `sh` there is equivalent to `/usr/bin/env curIP=123 script01`; could arguably eek out a tiny bit more speed by using the smaller tool.